# Abrir várias abas em um link JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Esse script é para abrir duas abas ou mais no navegador em um único link. Ao clicar no link abre só uma nova aba e a outra é bloqueado como pop-ups pelo navegador. Como eu faço para não bloquear? Ou tem outra maneira de abrir várias abas em um único link?

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function teste() {
    window.open("www.google.com.br", "_blank");
    window.open("www.gmail.com.br", "_blank");
}
</script>

<a href="javascript:teste();">Clique aqui para abrir as abas</a>
```

Comment: Essa pergunta já foi respondida aqui na comunidade. Dei uma rápida busca no diretório da StackOverflow e consegui achar a resposta. [Abrir solução](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28892291/how-to-open-multiple-javascript-pop-ups-at-the-same-time).

Comment: #vdschuck Corrigido o código estava errado, eu testei esta certo, e tenta o código.

Answer (score 1):

Não é mais possível fazer isso em navegadores recentes ou que contém bloqueador de popups, portanto, se `window.open(...)` não retornar um objeto ou retornar `undefined` ou `null`, você pode saber se o mesmo popup foi bloqueado, porém ainda não irá conseguir abrir várias abas ao mesmo tempo enquanto o seu bloco de código não é executado.

```
if (!window.open("www.google.com.br", "_blank")) {
    /* Popup bloqueado. O que fazer? */
}
```

Eu acho melhor não tentar mais abrir várias abas ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: só por estudo: existem algumas soluções à volta disso, nomeadamente simular um clique feito pelo utilizador ;)

Comment: @MoshMage Ou seja, vai precisar que o utilizador clique manualmente. De qualquer forma não sei quase nada sobre essas janelas nativas

Comment: não, só precisas de fazer com que o pointer se mexa e clique no botao como um user o faria normalmente

Comment: @MoshMage Não, o navegador não expõe nenhuma possibilidade de mover o cursor, e `HTMLElement#click` é bloqueado por padrão (nunca testei esse método junto com popups na verdade, mas já testei com requestFullscreen)

Comment: [uma resposta no SO-EN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey/14483616#14483616); also, abre a consola e dá-lhe `document.querySelector('.comment-help-link').click()` e topa se a ajuda dos comentarios nao abre. (ps, obviamente, a janela de comtar tem q tar aberta)

Comment: @MoshMage Eu já falei sobre o método `HTMLElement#click`, vê meu comentário acima. Mas vou testar a resposta dessa questão depois porque minha mãe vai para igreja